# Upper and lower bounds for $P(X+Y \leq a)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $\varepsilon>0$. I want to show that
$$
P(X \leq a - \varepsilon) - P( |Y| \geq \varepsilon) \leq P(X+Y \leq a) \leq P(X \leq a + \varepsilon) + P( |Y| \geq \varepsilon).
$$

The lower bound can be obtained as follows:

\begin{align}
P(X+Y \leq a) \geq P( X \leq a-\varepsilon, |Y| < \varepsilon) &= 1 - P(\{X > a-\varepsilon)\} \cup \{ |Y| \geq \varepsilon \} ) \\
&\geq 1 - P(X > a-\varepsilon) - P(|Y| \geq \varepsilon) \\
&= P ( X \leq a - \varepsilon)-P(|Y| \geq \varepsilon).
\end{align}

But how can one obtain the upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe that:

$$\{X+Y\le a\}\subseteq\{X\le a+\epsilon\}\cup \{|Y|\ge \epsilon\}$$

Indeed, if $X+Y\le a$. then either $X\le a+\epsilon$ or $X>a+\epsilon$.

In the latter case ($X>a+\epsilon$) we have $a\ge X+Y>a+\epsilon+Y$, so $Y<-\epsilon$ which implies $|Y|\ge \epsilon$

Consequently:

$$P(X+Y\le a)\le P(\{X\le a+\epsilon\}\cup \{|Y|\ge \epsilon\})\le P(X\le a+\epsilon)+P(|Y|\ge \epsilon)$$